# How do I make XAMPP use the paths from my Wordpress themes folder?

Tags: css, wordpress, xampp, relative-path, lampp

I'm having an issue where I have a local Wordpress install on my Ubuntu machine using XAMPP and I'm trying to work on a theme from scratch. The problem is that any path in index.php that's supposed to refer to other files in the same folder (e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css">`) is supposed to point to the CSS file in the same folder (`/opt/LAMPP/htdocs/blog/wp-content/themes/mytheme`).

Instead the file doesn't load and my browser reveals that it's not found. It turns out my browser is looking way up in the `/blog` folder. So for my page to load properly, I have to move everything there, or have the paths descend.

This is incredibly annoying because I have my XAMPP server set up with the same hierarchy as my site is going to have, and I don't want to have to hand-edit all my paths just so that it works like it should on my main website. Does anyone know how I can fix this so that XAMPP/Wordpress will look to load the theme from the `/mytheme` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the following line when i want to reference something in the themes directory:

`<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>`

For example if i want to load a style sheet contained in mytheme/css i do the following:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/css/stylesheet.css">`

Hope this helps.

Comment: `template_directory` does not work here for whatever reason. I used `stylesheet_url` instead and that works right away. But thanks anyway, it would have taken longer to figure it out if you hadn't made me think to try using the API in the first place.

Comment: It might be worth figuring out why `template_directory` isnt working as its very useful when calling images etc.

Comment: I checked, and after echoing the output realized that when I modified the partial URI, I left out the leading slash, and `template_directory` does not have a trailing slash. So yet another learning experience for me today.